# Is there an item that boosts some stat based on map completion percentage?

Tags: castlevania-series

I think there's a ring that boosts some stat based on how much of the map is explored, but the Castlevania Wiki on [Rings](https://castlevania.fandom.com/wiki/Ring) doesn't have anything that says Map / Explore / Rate.

And general Google searches haven't found me anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scout Armor (or Walk Armor in Castlevania: Symphony of the Night) is the only item I'm aware of that has any stats that are dependent on map coverage. Its defense stat will increase based on how much of the map you've uncovered. When the map is fully uncovered (or nearly complete), it usually makes this one of the highest Def armors in its respective game.

https://castlevania.fandom.com/wiki/Scout_Armor

Comment: Hmm, I have neither of the games that appears in, so I guess I just read about it somewhere?"